# Excel VBA Iterating Through Files - Stuck in a Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do the following:

1. specify a folder (containinf *.xlsm files)
2. Iterate through all the files
3. open each file, run a macro, close and save the file
4. Move onto next file until all have been done.

The code below works, BUT the loop never ends... its as if every time I save the file that's just been worked on, it appears as a new item in the list of files to go through.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
Sub runMe()

    Dim objFSO As Object
        Dim objFolder As Object
        Dim objFile As Object
        Dim MyPath As String
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim myDir As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    myDir = "\templates"
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Path
    MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & myDir

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Get the folder object associated with the directory
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyPath)

    'Loop through the Files 

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If InStr(objFile.Name, "~") = 0 And InStr(objFile.Name, ".xlsm") <> 0 Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(objFile, 3)
            Application.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!doMacro"
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
           ' Gets stuck in this loop
           ' WHY DOES IT KEEP LOOPING?
        End If
    Next

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. What you are exactly doing in the doMacro part? It is affecting the files in some way?

Comment: Problems like this are most easily tracked down by setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting variables as you go. It's not complicated code so this should be a matter of minutes to debug.

Comment: This will probably not resolve your problem, but `Workbooks.Open` takes a `String` as a first argument (or something that can be cast to a `String`).

Comment: @Ioannis The default parameter of a `File` COM object is its path, you can cast it as string without problems. It's just not as explicit and obvious, but it works.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for clarifying: interesting that default is `Path` and not `Name` - something new learned today :)

Comment: @Ioannis http://i.imgur.com/y6FIppN.png, note the small blue dot that signifies the default member of a COM class.

Comment: Have you thought of the possibility to write vp script so you dont actualy need to open up a workbook to start the code?

Comment: @Tomalak I added debug.print File in the for each loop to see the filename of each file being processed and the same files keep getting looped through. Its as if every time I modify the file and SAVE it, it joins the end of the 'queue' as a new file to be looped through.

Comment: Curious. Does it do things correctly when you close the file withot saving changes?

Comment: Yes, that's the key. If I just toggle `wb.Close SaveChanges:=False` then it works as expected... runs through files once and stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your comment, I think that the problem is that when you save the file it is somehow added back to the `FSO.GetFolder(path).Files` collection Iteration. A way to work around this is to build an array with the file names and then execute your loop. The relevant code is below:

```
Dim aux As String, Paths as Variant, Path as Variant

For Each File In FSO.GetFolder(path).Files
    If Not File.Name Like "~*" And File.Name Like "*.xlsm" Then
       aux = aux & File.Path & ";"
    End If
Next File

If Len(aux) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'No file matches the criteria
Paths = Split(Left(aux, Len(aux) -1), ";") 'Builds an array with the filenames

For Each Path In Paths
    With Workbooks.Open(Path, 3)
        Application.Run "'" & .Name & "'!doMacro"
        .Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With
Next Path
```

I built a string separated by ";" and then used `Split` to build an array to avoid using indexes, `ReDim Preserve` statements or to test if the filename is empty

Comment: Thanks @kbsou Funnily enough, in a roundabout way, I came to the same solution. I iterated through the files into a temp array (in my lame case, I put them in a named array) then looped through them. Think this is solving it. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub runMe()
    Dim FSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim File As Scripting.File
    Dim path As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\templates"

    For Each File In FSO.GetFolder(path).Files
        If InStr(File.Name, "~") = 0 _
           And LCase(FSO.GetExtensionName(File.Name)) = "xlsm" _
        Then
            With Workbooks.Open(File.Path, 3)
                Application.Run "'" & .Name & "'!doMacro"
                .Close SaveChanges:=True
            En With
        End If
    Next

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Your `For Each` loop can by definition not run forever, the error must be some place else, presumably in whatever `doMacro` does.

Subjective notes:

- Include a reference to `scrrun.dll` in your VBA project. This is useful for early binding (`New Scripting.FileSystemObject`) and it gives you code completion for those objects.
- `GetExtensionName()` is useful to get a file extension.
- Drop the Hungarian notation, you are not using it consistently anyway.
- You don't need a helper variable for `For Each`.
- You can use a `With` block to substitute the other helper variable (`wb`).

Comment: Thanks for the comments (bit of a novice as you can tell, this code is cobbled together from different snippets I find). doMacro just copies and pastes some values within the opened File. So it is changing it and then I call the .Close with saves...  If I add debug.print File then I see each file (2 diff in this case) just being opened and closed, repeating.